# Determining the event location on an oscillatory signal

Tags: python, math, events, signal-processing, numerical-integration

I am doing an event-driven integration and one of the events should detect when a signal has the amplitude lower than some value/limit.

In example, a decaying sine signal:

```
signal = sin(t)*exp(-t/50)
limit = 0.05
```

[image: Decaying sine signal]

From the figure, it can be seen that the condtition should be met at `t =~ 90`. Although I can see it, I would like to get the location numerically during integration. How can I do this? How can I define the condition?

Note: If I just take the first crossing of the `limit = 0.05` it occurs at `t =~ 0.05`, which is obviously not what I want.

Comment: What you mean is that you need to detect when a local peak value doesn't exceed a threshold. You could analyse in reverse-time, or you could differentiate and only compare with threshold at points where gradient is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the envelope using either `scipy.signal.hilbert`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

# Add some padding to limit the periodic extension effect
padlen = int(np.floor(0.1*len(x)))
y = np.pad(x, (0,padlen), mode='edge');
# Compute the envelope
envelope = np.abs(signal.hilbert(y));
# Truncate to the original signal length
envelope = envelope[:-padlen]
```

Or using a simple [diode detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_detector#Diode_detector) implementation:

```
def diode_detector(x,alpha):
    xmax = abs(x[0])
    y = np.array(x)
    for i in np.arange(len(x)):
        if (xmax < abs(x[i])):
            xmax = abs(x[i])
        else:
            xmax = alpha*xmax
        y[i] = xmax
    return y

# you may need to tweak the alpha parameter depending on your signal bandwidth
envelope = diode_detector(x,0.9997)
```

Then it simply a question of computing the trigger location:

```
T = t[1]-t[0]
print T*np.min(np.where(envelope < limit))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may calculate [envelop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(waves))e of you signal, filter it with low-pass filter if needed (noise) and find where envelope crosses the limit level.

To find envelope, you could try calculate Hilbert transform H(t) of your signal F(t) to make orthogonal signal ([How to find HT using Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Discrete_Hilbert_transform)). Envelope is square root of  the sum of squares of source signal and orthogonal one.

```
E(t) = Sqrt(F^2(t) + H^2(t))
```

P.S. There are probably more simple ways to evaluate envelope, see wiki links for Envelope.